# How to delete key:value pair from req.user object

Tags: javascript, object, passport.js

Why does the delete operator on the req.user object not work?

```
let test = new Object(req.user);

console.log(test.password); // Get correct string

delete test.password;

console.log(test.password); // Get correct string, but expect undefined
```

Comment: Seems working as expected to me.

Answer (score 0):

#### This works for me

```js
let test = {user:"hello", password:"goodbye"};

console.log(test.password);
// output is:    hello

delete test.password;

console.log(test.password);
// output is:    undefined
```

Could you edit post a snippet with an explicit assignment at the top (rather than a reference to `req.user`, which we can't reproduce). See if the problem reproduces with that.

Comment: Yes, this works. But not when getting the values from req.user

Answer (score 0):

This line just creates a reference to an existing object:

```
let test = new Object(req.user);
```

It's the same thing as

```
let test = req.user;
```

So whether or not you can delete test.password depends on whether or not you can delete req.user.password (it's the same operation).  If req.user.password is not a writable property, you will get the behavior you describe.

```js
const req = {
  user: {}
};

Object.defineProperty(req.user, "password", {
  value: "123456",
  writable: false
});

let test = new Object(req.user);
console.log(test.password); // Get correct string
delete test.password;
console.log(test.password); // Get correct string, but expect undefined

const req2 = {
  user: {
    password: "123456"
  }
};

let test2 = new Object(req2.user);
console.log(test2.password); // Get correct string
delete test2.password;
console.log(test2.password); // This works as expected
```

Comment: Thanks - How would one create as brand new object in the fastest way that can be fully manipulated? 

If req.user.password is not a writable property <--- How can we test for that? (And why doesn't the delete operator throw an exception?)

Answer (score 0):

Use `new Object()` on an existing object, doesn't actually create a new object. All you get is a reference to the original one.

The original object (`req.user`) might have the `password` field as part of it's prototype, and not as an own property. Deleting it from the object does nothing, because it's not a part of the object.

Demo:

```js
const base = Object.create({user:"hello", password:"goodbye"});

const test = new Object(base);

console.log(test === base); // true - it's the same object

console.log({ pass: test.password, ownProp: test.hasOwnProperty('password') });

delete test.password;

console.log({ pass: test.password, ownProp: test.hasOwnProperty('password') });
```